# sql if statement in function

Tags: sql, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a fuction in visual basic and I'm sending a and b variables into the fuction. It does a lot of select statements as seen below:

SQL CODE

```
Select xxx where a=@a

union

Select yyy where u=@a
```

I want to add one more union with if statement.
I want to run one part `if @b=1` and other part `if @b=2`

```
union

if @b=1

select zzz

if @b=2

select ttt
```

I want to learn how to use union with if statement and correct syntax of it.

```
union

    if @b=1
begin

    select zzz
end

    else if( @b=2)

    select ttt
end
```

is it correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking question about visual basic or SQL? If SQL, the `select` statement has to select from a table. Please clarify.

Comment: well it's psedeuo code.
i need to learn syntax of union with IF statement, or CASE statement.

i'm sending a into sql code,

if a =5
xxxxxxx
if a=3
yyyyyy

can you show me syntax of it

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put your checks in the `WHERE` clause. If they fail now rows are selected and therefore no rows are added to the overall result.

```
...
UNION
SELECT ...
       WHERE @b = 1
UNION
SELECT ...
       WHERE @b = 2;
```